# What defines Scapy send / receive?

Tags: python, wifi, scapy

I'm doing some Wi-Fi scripting with Scapy and I wish to do a WPS request. As part of this I need to conduct a series of packets such as EAPOL (Start) followed by receiving an EAP (Request, Identity) packet from the router.

If I do a SRP(EAPOL) with an appropriate packet Scapy will timeout waiting for a response because it seems the identity request isn't an appropriate 'response' to the packet for whatever definition Scapy uses.

Alternatively I tried to start sniff() directly after sending the packet, however it doesn't seem to start in time for picking up the packet.

An independent sniffing thread (started in a separate console window) does see the AP response as below.

```
RadioTap / Dot11 / LLC / SNAP / EAPOL EAP_PACKET / EAP / Padding
```

So my questions are

- What defines a send / receive pair in Scapy? Why is the EAP packet not an appropriate receive?
- Given a sniff() call directly after isn't seeing the EAP packet, what would be an appropriate way to receive it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The send/receive pair is defined by the `answers` method implemented by a layer.

For example, here is the `answers` method for the `IP` layer:

```
def answers(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other,IP):
        return 0
    if conf.checkIPaddr and (self.dst != other.src):
        return 0
    if ( (self.proto == socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) and
         (isinstance(self.payload, ICMP)) and
         (self.payload.type in [3,4,5,11,12]) ):
        # ICMP error message
        return self.payload.payload.answers(other)

    else:
        if ( (conf.checkIPaddr and (self.src != other.dst)) or
             (self.proto != other.proto) ):
            return 0
        return self.payload.answers(other.payload)
```

What you want to do is to develop your own `answers(request, potential_response)` function and receive raw packets. Then, you use YOUR `answers` function to decide which of the raw packets is the answer.

To receive raw packets, you can use the `sniff` function:

```
sniff(count=1,timeout=0.001)
```

although as you found out, it has the drawback that it does not necessarily start in time. So, you want to take a look at the way `sniff` is implemented. Internally, it uses `conf.L2listen` which you can also use.

So, before sending the request, do `s=conf.L2listen()` and after it, do `s.recv(65536)` to receive a packet. You can use `sel = select([s],[],[],0.001)` to wait for a certain amount of time for packets to arrive. If `s in sel[0]`, then data can be read from the socket, otherwise timeout passed.

The timeout parameter is in seconds, so all of my examples specified a timeout of 1 millisecond.